# How to do the prediction for SVM in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, random-forest, prediction

I have 2 dataset, `train_val` and `test`. I want to build 3 models and use the models to predict the outcome. This is my 3 models:

```
#Model 1
rf.model <- randomForest(Survived ~ ., data = train_val, type = 'response')

#Model 2
svm.model.linear <- svm(Survived ~ ., data = train_val, kernel="linear", cost = 2, gamma = 0.1)

#Model 3
svm.model.radial <- svm(Survived ~ ., data = train_val, kernel="radial", cost = 10, gamma = 0.1)
```

After training the 3 models by using the code above, I use the following code to do the prediction:

```
prediction <- predict(rf.model, newdata = test)
```

The outpu for the `prediction` is:

[image]

Then I put the outcome into a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(PassengerId = 892:1309, Survived = prediction)
```

The output for the `df` is

[image]

So far everything working well, however, when I replaced the `rf.model` in `prediction` by `svm.model.linear`, then the output changed:

[image]

and hence, the dataframe also having error:
[image]

May I know what is the reason for that and how should I get the same output of `df` as when I was using `rf.model` previously? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**This is the full code from the post**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(Amelia)
library(corrgram)
library(caret)
library(randomForest)
library(e1071)


#Import train and test dataset
train <- read.csv("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Titanic/train.csv")
test <- read.csv("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Titanic/test.csv")

#Ensure dataset loaded correctly
head(train)
head(test)


train$set <- "train"
test$set <- "test"
test$Survived <- NA
full <- rbind(train,test)

summary(full)
str(full)


# Creating new training and testing data set
full <- dplyr::select(full,-PassengerId,-Ticket,-Cabin)

#Creating a new variable called Dependents
full$Dependents <- full$SibSp + full$Parch
head(full)


missing_values <- full %>% summarise(across(everything(), ~sum(is.na(.))/length(.)))
missing_values <- missing_values %>% pivot_longer(cols = everything(),names_to = "feature",values_to="missing_pct")

ggplot(missing_values,aes(x=reorder(feature,-missing_pct),y=missing_pct,label=missing_pct)) + geom_text(hjust = 0,aes(label=scales::percent(missing_pct))) +
  geom_col(fill='red') + coord_flip() + scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent)


#Overview of scatterplots between all variables
full$Sex <- factor(full$Sex)
full$Sex.factor <- as.numeric(full$Sex)
str(full)
full %>% filter(set == "train") %>% select(-Name,-Embarked,-set,-SibSp,-Parch) %>% corrgram(lower.panel = panel.shade,upper.panel = panel.pie)


full$Survived <- as.factor(full$Survived)
full$Pclass <- as.factor(full$Pclass)
full %>% filter(set == "train") %>% ggplot(aes(Sex)) + geom_bar(aes(fill=Survived))
full %>% filter(set == "train") %>% ggplot(aes(Pclass)) + geom_bar(aes(fill=Survived))
full %>% filter(set == "train") %>% ggplot(aes(Age)) + geom_histogram(bins=10,aes(fill=Survived))
full %>% filter(set == "train") %>% ggplot(aes(Dependents)) + geom_histogram(bins=10,aes(fill=Survived))


full %>% ggplot(aes(x=Pclass,y=Age)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Pclass))
full %>% ggplot(aes(x=Sex,y=Age)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Sex))


#Getting the median age based on Pclass
p1MedAge <- full %>% filter(Pclass == 1 & Age != "NA") %>% summarise(median(Age)) %>% as.numeric()
p2MedAge <- full %>% filter(Pclass == 2 & Age != "NA") %>% summarise(median(Age)) %>% as.numeric()
p3MedAge <- full %>% filter(Pclass == 3 & Age != "NA") %>% summarise(median(Age)) %>% as.numeric()


#Imputing median age to missing data for train data
full$Age[is.na(full$Age) & full$Pclass == 1] <- p1MedAge
full$Age[is.na(full$Age) & full$Pclass == 2] <- p2MedAge
full$Age[is.na(full$Age) & full$Pclass == 3] <- p3MedAge

#Checking for missing age data
any(is.na(full$Age)
    
  
full[is.na(full$Fare),]
    
    
#Imputing the mean fare for Pclass 3
full$Fare[is.na(full$Fare)] <- round(mean(subset(full$Fare, full$Pclass == 3),na.rm = T),0)

#Final check of missing data
any(is.na(subset(full,select=-c(Survived))))


full <- full %>% select(-Name,-SibSp,-Parch,-Sex.factor)
str(full)


full$Dependents <- factor(full$Dependents)
full$Embarked <- factor(full$Embarked)
str(full)


train <- full %>% filter(set == "train") %>% select(-set)
test <- full %>% filter (set == "test") %>% select(-set)

#Creating data partition to cross validation
ind = createDataPartition(train$Survived,times = 1,p = 0.8,list = FALSE)
train_val <- train[ind,]
test_val <- train[-ind,]

#Checking distribution of data partition
round(prop.table(table(train$Survived)*100),digits=3)
round(prop.table(table(train_val$Survived)*100),digits=3)
round(prop.table(table(test_val$Survived)*100),digits=3)


log.model <- glm(formula = Survived ~ . - Fare - Embarked, data = train_val, family = binomial(link='logit'))
summary(log.model)


glm.prediction <- predict(log.model, newdata=test_val, type='response')
glm.prediction <- ifelse(glm.prediction >= 0.5, 1, 0)

table(test_val$Survived,glm.prediction)
sum(test_val$Survived==glm.prediction) / nrow(test_val)


rf.model <- randomForest(Survived ~ ., data = train_val)
print(rf.model$confusion)
importance(rf.model)


rf.prediction <- predict(rf.model, test_val)
table(test_val$Survived,rf.prediction)
sum(test_val$Survived==rf.prediction) / nrow(test_val)


tuned.svm.linear <- tune.svm(Survived ~., data = train, kernel = "linear", cost = c(0.01,0.1,0.2,0.5,0.8,1,2,3,5,10),gamma=c(0.1,0.5,1,2,5))
summary(tuned.svm.linear)
tuned.svm.radial <- tune.svm(Survived ~., data = train, kernel = "radial", cost = c(0.01,0.1,0.2,0.5,0.8,1,2,3,5,10),gamma=c(0.1,0.5,1,2,5))
summary(tuned.svm.radial)


svm.model.linear <- svm(Survived ~ ., data = train_val, kernel="linear", cost = 2, gamma = 0.1)
svm.model.radial <- svm(Survived ~ ., data = train_val, kernel="radial", cost = 10, gamma = 0.1)

svm.prediction.linear <- predict(svm.model.linear, test_val)
table(test_val$Survived,svm.prediction.linear)
sum(test_val$Survived==svm.prediction.linear) / nrow(test_val)

svm.prediction.radial <- predict(svm.model.radial, test_val)
table(test_val$Survived,svm.prediction.radial)
sum(test_val$Survived==svm.prediction.radial) / nrow(test_val)


#Predicting Survival on test data set using Random Forest model
rf.model <- randomForest(Survived ~ ., data = train, type = 'response')
prediction <- predict(svm.model.linear, newdata = test)

submission <- data.frame(PassengerId = 892:1309, Survived = prediction)
write.csv(submission, file = "submission.csv", row.names = FALSE)
paste("Your submission was successfully saved!")
```

**This is where the error occured when I run the code**
[image]

As you can see, when I run until the line `submission <- data.frame(PassengerId = 892:1309, Survived = prediction)`, the error appeared.

Comment: I assumed this was the titanic dataset, and tried re-running your code. SVM prediction seemed to work fine for me. Maybe include more of your code so we can see how you generated train_val and test. Have you converted Survived to a factor before building your models?

Comment: Hi rw2, thanks for your reply, yes this is titanic dataset. I'm actually trying to follow exactly what this post is doing: https://www.kaggle.com/jameaplays/titanic-glm-rf-svm-model?scriptVersionId=86041144#1659238  The only thing I changed is replacing the `rf.model` in `predict` to `svm.model.linear` as shown in my question. Or if you don't mind, can you share the code on how you do the prediction with `svm.model.linear` in the `predict` function and at the same time still can obtain `df` without error?

Comment: Thanks for the info. Code snippet 21 on that post shows prediction with the svm model. I ran the code from the start of the post, and the svm predictions worked fine, and were in exactly the same format as the random forest predictions. Maybe try starting from scratch and make sure you run everything in the same order as shown in the post - its possible you've changed the tables/structure at some point without realising. If you still have trouble let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the testing, I run everything exactly the same as in the kaggle post but still get the error. I edited my question with 2 new sections: `The code that I run` and `The screenshot of the error`. Not too sure what is going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong table as your `newdata`.

You should be using `test_val` which has gone through the same treatment as `train_val`. Instead you are training using `train_val`, but using `test` as your `newdata`.

If you make predictions for your `test_val` table, both the svm and random forest models will work, and will give you 177 predictions.

You will also need to change your `submission` data.frame to have 177 rows instead of 418.

**EDIT**
As discussed in the comments (although they've now been removed?), you want to predict for the `test` data using a model built on the `train` data.

Try this:

```
svm.model.linear <- svm(Survived ~ ., data = train, kernel="linear", cost = 2, gamma = 0.1)
svm.prediction.linear <- predict(svm.model.linear, test[,-1])
```

The `predict` function works slightly differently for different models in R, which can cause confusion. When you use it with an svm model it is actually calling `predict.svm()`. This particular function doesn't like that you are passing it `newdata` with an empty `Survived` column. If you remove that column by specifying `newdata=test[,-1]` then the prediction will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how should I change this part `PassengerId = 892:1309` so that it have 177 rows instead?

Comment: No problem - please accept if it has helped.
Just change the length of the PassengerID column to be 177 e.g. `PassengerID = 892:1068`
I'm not familiar with the data so don't know why you start at ID 892? What is `PassengerID` supposed to refer to?